# In a cricket championship, there are 21 matches. If each team plays one match with every other team, the number of teams is

Tags: permutations, combinations

This is either a permutation or a combination question. I suspect it is a combination. Does it require using algebra because there is no n provided? 
Sorry, I am really weak on this topic. Thank you for helping out!!!

Comment: You need to consider all combinations of two teams out of $n$. This results in ${n \choose 2} = 21 \iff \frac{n (n-1)}{2} = 21 \iff n = 7.$

Comment: @jvdhooft Hey man, thanks a lot for your help!!!!

Comment: @jvdhooft how do you get n(n-1)/2 ??? wouldnt be (n/n-2) x ( 1/2!) ??? sorry and thank you

Comment: @MERcurialKG: Since $2!=2,$ then $$\binom{n}{2}=\frac{n!}{(n-2)!2!}=\frac{(n-2)!n(n-1)}{(n-2)!2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}.$$

Comment: yes @Cameron Buie but how do you get n(n-1)???

Comment: @MERcurialKG: Sorry about that. I realized I hadn't fully explained, so I edited my comment. If you reload the page, you should see the finished form.

Comment: wouldnt be n/(n-r) x 1/2!???

Comment: In general, if $r$ and $n$ are integers, and $0\le r\le n,$ then $$\binom{n}{r}=\frac{n!}{(n-r)!r!}.$$ In this case, we're considering $r=2.$

Comment: I am really sorry and i can see you are so kind and trying to help me but i still dont get how you get (n−2)!n(n−1)/(n−2)!2. Why is (n-2)! suddenly be on top and (n-1) appeared?

Comment: That is because $$n!=n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots2\cdot1,$$ while $$(n-2)!=(n-2)(n-3)\cdots2\cdot 1,$$ so that $$n!=n\cdot(n-1)\cdot(n-2)!$$ Does that make sense? (P.S.: I don't need to tag you, because it's your post. However, since more that just you and I have been commenting, you do need to tag me, or I won't see your replies without checking.)

Comment: @CameronBuie Ohh God Bless you! Thank you, thank you soo frinkin much!!! Thanks for the explanation!!!!! You deserve a double coated Chocolate Ice Cream!!!! Can i report you for being a kind person??(Sorry i am new to the site)

Comment: Ha! Reporting kindness would be quite a feature! :-) I'm glad to help. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose there are $n$ teams, call them Team $1,\ldots,n$. Now Team $1$ plays Team $2,\ldots,n$ (total of $(n-1)$ matches), Team $2$ plays Team $3,...,n$ (total of $(n-2)$ matches), and so on. So the total number of matches is $(n-1)+(n-2)+\ldots+1=21$.

$21$ is a small number and in this case you can see that since $1+2+3+4+5+6=21$, we have $n=7$.

Comment: Hey @Jasper Loy I do not understand your meaning sorry. Where do you get the 6 from? sorry im slow and Thanks for replying@!!!!!

Comment: ok cool thanks!!